# RSpec testing a controller to restrict user behaviour on Rails 3.2

Tags: rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

I am trying to restrict user to be a admin on performing specific action. In the following, when user sign_in (not an admin), it should not access the actions from the passed in hash. Here is the piece of RSpec code it **works** but have a question on that hash passed in:

```
  { "new"   => "get",
  "create"  => "post",
  "edit"    => "get",
  "update"  => "put",
  "destroy" => "delete" }.each do |action, method|
    it "cannot access the #{action} action" do
      sign_in(:user, user)
      send(method, action.dup, :id => project.id)
      response.should redirect_to(root_path)
      flash[:alert].should eql("You must be an admin to do that.")
    end
  end
```

I am wondering why here use the string `"new"`, `"create"`, ... Instead of using symbol like `:new`, `:create`? Is it something related to `action.dup` in later `send` method call??

Thanks!

Comment: why is the dup method needed, seems to work without it?, then could use symbols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that Symbols don't have a `.dup` method, but Strings do. Try doing this in IRB or in the Rails console and you'll see that it fails.

However, that's for the action. I'm not sure if the `method` could be a Symbol. You could try it out though.

Comment: I tested. Symbol and Strings do have `dup` and `clone`. I use ruby 1.9.3. This still not clear my confusion, thanks though.

Comment: It's a fronzen string issue in ruby 1.9.2, though.